# Counting fishes on an image

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, opencv, python

I want to build a script that can count and box fishes in a given image with the assumption that the image will always contain fishes (any number) and no other animals.

My current approach is just to count the number of contours detected in an image. I use canny edge detection with dilation and erosion. I also discard contours that are too small, treating them as noise.

This approach seems to be working fine if the fishes are nicely separated. But once they are intersecting, or covering each other, things start to get messy.

Currently, I am just using images from google.

What other approach can I use for this problem? Still a newbie in image processing.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Post some of your code..

Comment: I just want to ask for other approach i can use, just like what I have said in my post. My code seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

> What other approach can I use for this problem?

You can try to detect just a particular feature of the fish, such as an eye, mouth, or fin. You can try to detect whole fish, and *also* count particular features as above; if the numbers don't match you can deduce that you've found some partial fish.